# Branching to labels

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing a MIPS code for a simple calculator, and was wondering how you branch to the corresponding function according to the user input.  For example, if the user wishes to add two numbers, how would you make sure the calculator jumps to the add label, instead of perhaps the multiply or subtract?

Comment: Please post some more info. What do you have, what do you need. Do you already have some code you can show us?

Comment: I have code that when the user inputs a function to be performed (+-*/), its stores it as an ascii value in one of the temporary registers.  My question is then, how do I make sure that for the function the user has entered it jumps to the correct label that carries out the function.
For example it jumps to the add and not subtract (as shown below), if the user wants to add the numbers.
addnum: 
        add.s $f12, $f1, $f0    # Add together numbers and put in syscall result register
        j       result
 
subnum: 
        sub.s $f12, $f1, $f0    
        j       result

Comment: I rolled back the addition of `[homework]` -- you need to ask first before tagging it, in this case.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take user input into a register.

Then compare that to the first ascii value, say '+', using a beq instruction.

```
.data
plus: .asciiz "+"
sub:  .asciiz "-"
prod: .asciiz "*"
div   .asciiz "/"

.text
.global calculator
.align 2
.ent calculator

calculator:
    //t0 holds user input

    la  $t1,plus
    lb  $t1,0($t1)
    beq $t0,$t1,add

    //now check for subtraction, division product. Same code, just change the address (add)

    //if none matched, jump to error
    b   error

add:
    //addition code goes here
division:
    //division code goes here
product:
    //product code goes here
subtraction:
    //subtraction code goes here.

error:
   //error code goes here.
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this method can only work for 3 different types of input, not 4.  So how can I make sure it branches to another label if there is a 4th value it has to be compared to?
Say the user inputs '+' (ascii  43) and it is compared to the ascii  45 (-), you can use branch if less than but the ascii for '*' is also less than 45, so how do I make sure it goes to  the '+' label rather than the '*'.

Comment: dont think of it in terms of greater / lower than. Think of it more like a switch statement.

Comment: I have coded an example of this. Will post it if neccesary, but try to understand this.